# What is more expensive? Reading or comparing integers, doubles

Tags: c++

I asked myself, which Big O Notation C++ min has.

I want the minima from a Set of integers.

I saw in stackoverflow a similar question.

> The answer was O(n), because you have to read n numbers.

But this is only correct, if reading is the critical operation.

**My question is: What is more expensive? (in cpu clocks or whatever)
Reading or comparing?**

Comment: `O(n)` determines the behaviour of an algorithm (especially for large numbers). It does not matter whether you execute `read` or `compare` operations, or both.

Comment: You are mixing two distinct things. The `O(n)` notation doesn't care which operation is more expensive. `O(n)` says that the number of operations is direct proportional with the number of items you compare. If you double the number of items, the time doubles. `O(n^2)` for example, says that when you triple the number of items, the time to process them multiplies by 9 (i.e. `3^2`)

Comment: Your own statement within the question ("in cpu clocks or whatever") implies that the answer depends on the underlying platform (HW architecture + designated compiler). In short, the C++ language standard does not define the "price" of each machine operation (in fact, it doesn't even refer to machine operations in any other manner, as the language is agnostic to whatever machine is used for executing the program).

Comment: so there is no difference between O(n) and O(log(n))?
I don't think so.
The fact is, that you don't need to compare n times to find the min.

Comment: Yes there is, but but in O notation there is no difference between performing n operations and performing 1000*n operations, both are O(n). Also, there is no difference between operations taking 5*n seconds and operations taking 1000*n seconds, both scale linearly in n.

Comment: I think you don't understand the real problem. I think this is my mistake.
Searching for the min needs (min) 2 operations. Reading and comparing.
If reading >> comparing, it's O(n), otherwise something else.

Comment: So 2n operations? That's O(n)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the platform, but almost surely reading values from memory is more expensive than the operations on the CPU. But, on the topic of big o notation - it's not about which operation is more expensive. It's about the fact that the algorithm scales with the number of inputs (i.e. n).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second statement is true and false. The algorithm determines the function in Big O. The function counts the critical operations needed to complete the algorithm. The functions input is the number of inputs (i.e. n).
Min for example has a different Big O Notation, if < is the critical operation, which could be interesting if you use your own weak order.

Comment: It's not false. You're saying writing an algorithm in a different way would change the original's complexity. That's not true. You're now evaluating a completely new algorithm. The complexity is dependent on the algorithm, not the end result.

Comment: Yeah, I think there is some confusion as to what o-notation *is* by the OP. It has everything to do with algorithm complexity when scaling up and *nothing* to do with CPU load of the algorithm or individual operations of the algorithm. Two different algorithms can be O(n) with one algorithm being 100000x slower than the other.

Comment: And nevermind that there's also something called little-o complexity as well. ;) But not to confuse things..